# How much ram can Install on my PQ5 PRO Motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

I have a PQ5 PRO Asus motherboard. I have 4 RAM slots and a windows ultimate instalation (64 bit). I already found out that my motherboard does not support DDR3 RAM, What are the biggest ram sticks available for my motherboard? Also would my motherboard support an AMD FX 8-Core Black Edition FX-8150 (FD8150FRGUBOX) Processor?

Comment: Did you make any effort at all yourself to find the answer? -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

16 GB is the max your board will take.

No, it won't support the AMD FX 8-Core Black Edition processor.

http://uk.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5Q_PRO/#specifications

[image]